# Need eJunkie to Return To My Site After eBook Purchase

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

I sell ebooks via eJunkie and payment is collected with PayPal; website is with Weebly.  I paste the 'add to cart' button on my website and when people buy my product they are directed to a FatFreeCart page:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/tp33gd4fx]

eJunkie, on it's [page](http://www.e-junkie.com/ej/help.redirection.htm), says "Product-specific Redirection cannot be combined with File Downloads for the same product, as they are mutually-exclusive types of digital-product delivery" so I will need some sort of a secure work around.  A few ideas are posted on the above link.

Could anyone describe in simple terms what the solution would look like.

Comment: If you want your name to show on your post, please change your display name from user#### to the name you want to use in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your standard E-junkie-generated thank-you/download page to include a link back to your site, you can add the HTML for that link in your E-junkie Seller Admin > Account Preferences > Common Thank-you Page HTML -- whatever you put in there will be added to every thank-you page we generate for you.  E.g., the link HTML you'd add would look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/>Return to PPE Products</a>
```

If you'd rather just redirect buyers back to your site after checkout, then rather than using product-specific Redirection (which cannot be used with Single File Download products), you can redirect all your orders to a Common Thank-you Page URL on your site regardless of the item(s) ordered; you can enter this URL in the Account Preferences screen of your E-junkie Seller Admin.  In this case, you should also remove the `[%thankyou_link%]` template tag from your Common Thank-you Email message template (also in Account Preferences), or just delete that entire template to disable this message.

Bear in mind this means your buyers will be unable to claim their download immediately following checkout for "instant gratification", because you'd be bypassing your standard E-junkie-generated thank-you page where we provide the download link; instead, buyers would need to wait to receive a product-specific thank-you email message for each item they purchase, providing a link to their download page for that item.

BTW, we don't routinely monitor third-party support sites like StackOverflow, so it's lucky our PR staff happened across your post here.  For a prompt response from E-junkie support in the future, please use the Contact link on our site to email us, or post to our site's Community forum.